# Missing AWS Beanstalk Amazon Linux 2 Platform Hooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

I'm migrating Beanstalk applications from old platforms to the new Amazon Linux 2-based platforms. AWS docs point out how to modify some of the custom platform hooks that no longer work, but some are left out of the docs.

Specifically, I have hooks in these lifecycle events that do not appear to be supported in Amazon Linux 2 platform versions:

- /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/restartappserver/pre
- /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/postinit

Does Beanstalk no longer support hooks for these types of events? It's a big oversight from Amazon if so - how are applications intended to migrate if they're not providing a 1-to-1 replacement?

I've reviewed docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html to see how platform hooks are intended to work. Note that on this page, hooks are described for app and config deploys prebuild, predeploy, and postdeploy ONLY. No mention of hooks for postinit or restartappserver.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Beanstalk no longer support hooks for these types of events?

Correct - on Amazon Linux 2 (AL2) platforms, custom platform hooks in the `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/` folder have entirely been discontinued.

> How are applications intended to migrate if they're not providing a 1-to-1 replacement?

If you intend to upgrade to Amazon Linux 2, you need to change your application workflow to use the `prebuild`, `predeploy` and `postdeploy` hooks.

If you can't, you need to remain on Amazon Linux 1.

Unfortunately, as you've noticed, a 1-to-1 replacement has not been provided.

Comment: I was afraid this was the answer. Remaining on Amazon Linux 1 isn't really an option for me anymore as they've retired the platform entirely. 

Any suggestions on how I can mimic restartappserver or postinit hooks using the new prebuild, predeploy and postdeploy hooks?

Comment: @CharlieJackson What are you actually doing in those scripts? It’s diverging a bit off the question but I’ll see if I can help 